# WITH RECOMPILE in stored procedure after setting parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to use the `WITH RECOMPILE` in a stored procedure after the declared parameter are filled with values. Where do I have to put it?
I want to do something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_dosomething 
    @AdrID INT = '32' 
                    WITH RECOMPILE
AS
    SELECT @AdrID = SELECT MAX(ID) 
                    FROM Address
    INSERT INTO TempStreet
    SELECT Streetname FROM Workadress WHERE ID = @AdrID
    INSERT INTO TempStreet
    SELECT Streetname FROM Homeadress WHERE ID = @AdrID
    OPTION(RECOMPILE)

    UPDATE TempStreet Set
    FROM TempStreet inner join AditionalData1...

    UPDATE TempStreet Set
    FROM TempStreet inner join AditionalData2...

    SELECT * FROM TempStreet
GO
```

So I want to set the parameter and then recompile the execution plan for the rest of the stored procedure every time it is executed.

The stored procedure does the followings things:
The Procedure is doing two different INSERT INTO a Table. After that the table is beeing updated by muptiple statements with joins on other tables. At the end there is a SELECT on that table.

What would be the right way to do it?
Would it be better to use **WITH RECOMPILE** or rather **OPTION(RECOMPILE)**

Please help me.

Comment: Is it a requirement to return multiple result sets?

Comment: You don't. As per the [syntax documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax) the `WITH` clause, and the procedure options (with includes `RECOMPILE`), goes **before** the `AS`. Your requirement is like asking how to define a query where the `FROM` is defined *before* the `SELECT`.

Comment: But WHY? It is highly unlikely - in this scenario - that recompiling does anything useful.  Your procedure has a parameter which the logic completely ignores, making this approach highly suspicious. Smells like both premature optimization and a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The Procedure is dooing two different Inserts into a Table. After that the table is beeing updated by muptiple statements with joins on other tables. At the end there is a SELECT on that table.

Comment: I don't see anything here that looks like it would need a RECOMPILE at all.  Why do you think that it needs one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_dosomething_sub @AdrID INT
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
    Select Streetname from Workadress where ID = @AdrID
    Select Streetname from Homeadress where ID = @AdrID
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_dosomething @AdrID INT = '32'
AS
    select @AdrID = Select max(ID) FROM Address
    EXEC sp_dosomething_sub @ArdID
GO
```

Note that I am not saying that this is necessarily a good idea, I'm just saying that it should do what you want.  It would take some pretty odd (or complex) circumstances for this to be a desirable approach.

Comment: I added a lettle description of the stored Procedure at the end of my qwestion. Could you have a look at it and say if WITH RECOMPILE would still be the right thing to use?

Answer (score 0):

I always say that everything is possible as long as you have the resources (which includes time, money, knowledge and more). This case is not different. In order to use this format, all that you need to do is to design and develop your own language, since this format is not a valid Transact SQL format.

Your question is like asking how can I calculate 1+1 and get 3. The answer is to build your own math, since is not fit for the common math language.

If I understand your needs (and not request) correctly then you can gain what you need by executing a stored procedure from another stored procedure.

You can write procedure X which configure the parameters and this procedure X will execute procedure Y which is configured using `WITH RECOMPILE`

Comment: Note! in most cases I HIGHLY recommend not to use `WITH RECOMPILE` and you should have a good reason to use it after you thought about the implications on performance.